# Cocos2d, How to change sprite image with timer and repeat process over again?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite that changes texture (basically different color). I want to change the texture over 30 seconds not instantly. How can I achieve this? Also, How can I repeat the process? So it should stay at blue for 30 seconds then go to red. Then repeat the process again

```
   sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"blue.png"];
   [sprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"red.png"] ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
id delayTime1 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2.0f];
id calFun1   = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    //HERE SET BLUE TEXTURE..

   sprite.color = ccc3(0,255,0);

}];
id delayTime2 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2.0f];
id calFun2   = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    //HERE SET RED TEXTURE..
   sprite.color = ccc3(255,0,0);

}];

id sequece = [CCSequence actions:delayTime1, calFun1, delayTime2, calFun2, nil];
id repeate = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequece];

[sprite runAction:repeate];
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in my situation, by any chance do you know how to change a color of sprite from blue to red? Someone said something about cocos2d changing colors with code

Comment: u can add custom color also,  sprite.color = ccc3(255,0,255);